# How to use Vue transition to expand and shrink a div

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, transition

Using Vue, I have two divs that I want to toggle with a transition.  I want slowly expand the div to my desired width on click, and then shrink on another click.  I can get the div to expand on one click, but can't figure out how to shrink it on the second click.

Not really clear if just specifying the width of the divs is enough, or if I also have to specify the same width in the css transition classes.

This fiddle shows what I've been trying: https://jsfiddle.net/vxmh8auo/1/

JS

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    showButton: true
  },
  methods: {
    randomise () { this.n = Math.random() }
  },
  components:{'input-div':blah}
});
```

CSS

```
.interaction {
  border: 10px solid lightgreen;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  max-height: 225px;
  transition: max-height 0.25s ease-out;
}

.default {
   width: 20px;
}
.bigger{
  width: 200px;
}

.expand-enter-active, .expand-leave-active {
  transition-property: width;
  transition-duration: 5s;
 }


.expand-leave-to {
 width: 200px;
}

.expand-enter{
  width: 20px;
}
```

HTML

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<div class="interaction">
    <button @click="showButton=!showButton">
     <transition name="expand" mode="out-in">
      <div v-if="showButton" v-bind:class="showButton ? 'default':'bigger'" key="small"> B </div>
      <div v-else class="bigger" key="big"> Bigger </div>
     <!--<input-div><</input-div>-->
      </transition>
    </button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you want to grow and shrink the same element or do you want to remove an element from the DOM and insert another on click?

Comment: @MarcRo I want to remove an element from the DOM and insert another.  I tried to simplify for the purposes of this, but what I'm trying to do is replace the button (which has small width) with a component (which has a larger width), and have the div grow to contain the component on click....

Comment: More like fixing the fiddle at https://jsfiddle.net/ba38Ln59/1/

Comment: Ah! Allright. Give both components (in their CSS) the final width you want them to have. In the `<transition>` element you transition the `max-width` from 0 to some arbitrarily big number.

Comment: @MarcRo - well the first element is a button, and second element should be a component (or in my fiddle a div containing a component).  Still unclear how this should work....my use case is essentially a button with a search icon that when clicked expands to an search component containing an input box where a user can type their search....

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this, add class 'default' and toggle class 'bigger':

```
  <button @click="toggleBigger">
     <transition name="expand" mode="out-in">
      <div  class="default" v-bind:class="{ bigger: showButton }" key="small"> B </div>

     <!--<input-div><</input-div>-->
      </transition>
    </button>
```

Add method toggleBigger, its more readable this way:

```
methods: {
    toggleBigger(){
    this.showButton = !this.showButton;
    }
```

And add transitions on your css classes directly like this:

```
.default {
  transition: max-height 0.25s ease-out;
   width: 20px;
    transition-property: width;
}
.bigger{
  transition: max-height 0.25s ease-out;
  width: 200px;
  transition-duration: 5s;
   transition-property: width;
}
```

You can see working fiddle [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/m07jndxk/)

PS I did not removed unnecessary classes from fiddle.

Comment: You shouldn't need to repeat the `transition` and `transition-property` styles for `.bigger`, since any elements with the `bigger` class also have the `default` class. And you only need the `transition-duration: 5s` if you actually want the expansion to be slower than the collapse.

Comment: I'm getting closer - just can't figure out how to get the component to disappear and be replaced with the button when closing: check out this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/35arL9fn/

Comment: Hey take a look at this, is this what you want to achieve? 
https://jsfiddle.net/6m3zL0ct/

Answer (score 0):

This seems so hackey and containing a lot of unnecessary classes, but it works: https://jsfiddle.net/df70pk68/

Again, my use case is a button that expands to a component with an input box and then shrinks again.  My solution was to immediately make the component opacity zero, then slowly shrink it.  The prevents the input box from breaching the border of the shrinking div.  I would love it if someone could figure out a more elegant way to do this....

HTML

```
<div id="app">
<div class="interaction">
    <button @click="showButton=!showButton">
     <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
      <div v-if="showButton" class="default" key="small"> B </div>
      <input-div class="bigger" v-else><</input-div>
      </transition>
    </button>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.interaction {
  border: 10px solid lightgreen;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  max-height: 225px;
}
```

JS

```
const blah = Vue.component('input-div',{
template: '<div><input type="text" readonly></div>'
});
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    showButton: true
  },
  components:{'input-div':blah}
});

.default {
   width: 20px;
}

.bigger{
   width: 250px;
}


.fade-leave-active {
  transition: all 5s ease;
 }

.fade-leave-to{
  width: 300px;
}
.bigger.fade-leave-to{
  width:20px;
  opacity: 0
}
.bigger.fade-leave-active{
  transition: opacity 0s ease;
  transition: width 5s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should forget vue's support on this, only use css3 can do that, and very simple.

first ,this is your div's code

```
<div id="my-div"></div>

#my-div{
transition: width 0.5s; /* this is the key code you need */
}
```

then, you can change the width of my-div use vue or js-dom or whatever, the magic thing will happen.